# Include Sepcified ids in result if condition is matching

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_match_players` (
  `player_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `player_match_id` int NOT NULL,
  `player_team` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `player_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `player_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1 = wicket keeper 2 = batsman 3 = all rounder 4 = bowler',
  `is_compulsory` mediumint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `player_points` mediumint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO `tbl_match_players` VALUES
( 1, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 1' , 1, 0, 0),
( 2, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 2' , 2, 0, 0),
( 3, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 3' , 2, 1, 0),
( 4, 2, 'Netherland', 'Player 4' , 2, 1, 0),
( 5, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 5' , 2, 0, 0),
( 6, 2, 'Netherland', 'Player 6' , 2, 0, 0),
( 7, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 7' , 2, 0, 0),
( 8, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 8' , 2, 0, 0),
( 9, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 9' , 4, 0, 0),
(10, 2, 'Netherland', 'Player 10', 4, 0, 0),
(11, 2, 'India'     , 'Player 11', 4, 0, 0);
```

and my current query is like this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id) AS batsman
FROM (
    SELECT player_id
    FROM tbl_match_players
    WHERE player_type = 2 AND player_match_id = 2
    ORDER BY is_compulsory DESC, RAND()
    LIMIT 5
)t ORDER BY RAND();
```

current query is including player_id in result if it have is_compulsory = 1 and then remain player_ids getting selected by random as per my limit given.

Now I want specify comma separated player_id with query so if where condition is matching then it should include that specified player_ids in result.

1. include specified player_ids if where condition is matching
2. include is_compulsory = 1 player_id if where condition is matching
3. remain player_id should be selected and included as per where condition and LIMIT

Like if I want specify player ids called 5,6 our query should return

```
5,6,3,4,2
or
5,6,3,4,7
```

Here is my [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GJqrxhni) for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: It makes no sense to have `ORDER BY` in the main query. You're returning a single row since there's no `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write separate queries for each criteria to include, and combine them with `UNION`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(player_id ORDER BY query_id, is_compulsory, RAND()) AS batsman
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS query_id, player_id, 0 AS is_compulsory
    FROM tbl_match_players
    WHERE player_id IN (5, 6)
    UNION ALL (
    SELECT 2 AS query_id, player_id, is_compulsory
    FROM tbl_match_players
    WHERE player_id NOT IN (5, 6)
    AND player_type = 2 AND player_match_id = 2
    ORDER BY is_compulsory DESC, RAND()
    LIMIT 5)
    LIMIT 5
) AS t
```